# Prove $F(y)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus

> Prove $$F(y)=\int_0^\infty e^{-(x+y)^2}\,dx$$ in continuous in $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: what is the integration domain? $\mathbb R $?

Comment: integration domain is from 0 to +∞

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If we substitute in $u=x+y$, we get that
$$F(y)=\int_{y}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \mathrm{d} u$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We get $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-(x+y)^2}dx=-1/2\,{\rm erf} \left(y\right)\sqrt {\pi}+1/2\,\sqrt {\pi}$$ where erf the so-called error function denotes.

Comment: integration domain is from 0 to +∞

Comment: Just corrected, thanks for your hint!

Comment: I am curious about how to prove it is continuous in (－∞，＋∞)

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Would you mind helping me write down the process of proof?